# Как можно сформировать проверку на строку?

Tags: c#

У меня есть проверка такого рода `GetName` если находит подходящую строчку в тексте `path` то возвращает определённый текст.

```
public static string GetName(string path)
{
   if (path.Contains("test"))
   {
       return "Stratring Test";
   }
   if (path.Contains("end"))
   {
       return "Ending Test";
   }
   if (path.Contains("beta"))
   {
       return "Beta Test";
   }
   // и.т.д очень много проверок
}
```

Можно ли как-нибудь сократить/улучшить данный вариант? Чтобы не писать много `if` и.т.д

Comment: Заведите класс с двумя свойствами — команда, сообщение, создайте коллекцию экземпляров этого класса и потом перебирайте ее в цикле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути ваш код можно переписать в нечто, похожее на это:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> NameCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["test"] = "Starting Test",
    ["end"] = "Ending Test",
    ["beta"] = "Beta Test"
};

public static string GetName(string path) 
    => NameCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => path.Contains(x.Key)).Value;
```

P.S. Заметили, что у вас постоянно повторяется `Test`? Я бы на вашем месте и его убрал бы, правда я не знаю какие у вас там другие `if/else`...

Comment: красивое решение)

Comment: Это может быть не эквивалентно коду с последовательными ифами, потому что порядок возврата значений при переборе словарем не гарантируется. Эквивалентно было бы List<KeyValuePair<,>>, но там уже и до решения с нормальным классом не далеко.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, такой код:

```
class name
{
    public string Path;
    public string _name;
}
```

В классе:

```
name[] names =
{
    { "test", "Startring Test" },
    { "end", "Ending Test" }
}; // с инициализацией массива мог накосячить, проверьте
```

Сам метод поиска:

```
public static string GetName(string path)
{
    foreach (name n in names)
        if (path.Contains(n.path))
            return n._name;
}
```